# Image navigation

Tags: c#

How to navigate the image using Keyboard arrow keys in C#.

My 1st form contains listView. Listview contains 10 images in thumbnail format.Images are from perticular folder. When i double click the image in the list view, its opening in a new window as large image. I want to navigate the image in the new window as per listview order.

If i click the image randomly, want to navigate the image from that selected image.

Its like a Microsoft picture manager.

Plz give me an Idea.

Comment: I assume you are referring to WinForm? Add event handler for key down event for your form, and change the image source as you desire. I didn't post this as answer cause it's not detailed and specific enough. You might need to add more handling of the image change if the sizes are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your form's KeyPreview property to True.  Then add this line of code to the top of your CS file:

```
using System.IO;
```

Next, inside the scope of your form, add these two lines:

```
private FileInfo[] _files;
private int _currentFile;
```

In your form's Load event, put this code:

```
DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(
    Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "images"));
_files = dirinfo.GetFiles();
_currentFile = 0;
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(_files[_currentFile].FullName);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Finally, in your form's KeyDown event, put this code:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
{
    _currentFile--;
    if (_currentFile < 0)
    {
        _currentFile = _files.Length - 1;
    }
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
{
    _currentFile++;
    if (_currentFile >= _files.Length)
    {
        _currentFile = 0;
    }
}

Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(_files[_currentFile].FullName);
if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

This code assumes that you have a PictureBox on your form named "pictureBox1", and it assumes that you have a folder named "\images" in your application folder that contains the image files you wish to display.

As o.k.w. mentioned in a comment, you may want to enhance this code by resizing the PictureBox to fit the dimensions of the image file.  You can do that by setting the SizeMode property of your PictureBox to AutoSize (or set it to CenterImage, if you wish to keep the overall image centered on your form).

Comment: @vijaii: you're welcome. When you get an answer to a question, it's customary to select it as the correct answer (click the checkmark).

Comment: one more Doubt Musi,

           Ur previous code is working perfectly, but one problem is there, plz check my recent edited question.

When i double click the image in the list view, its opening in a new window as large image. I want to navigate the image in the new window as per listview order.

                  plz give me an idea.

Comment: @vijaii: there are many different ways to handle this. The best way would depend on how you're loading the thumbnails into the ListView. One simple way would be to create a string[] array of the image paths in your 1st form as you're loading the images. Then, when a user double-clicks the ListView, you pass the string[] array and the index of the ListView's selected item to the new form. This would substitute for the code in the Load event in my above sample. Everything else would be pretty much the same.

Comment: An even simpler way might be to pass to the new form a reference to the ListView control on your 1st form. This way, you could have the up and down arrow keys change the picture *and* change the selected item in the ListView, so that they're kept in sync. When you initially load the image thumbnails into your ListView, you can set each ListViewItem's Tag property to the full path to the file, and then retrieve this property from your new form as the user goes forward and back through the list.